# Ajax - многократное повторение кода на PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть код, на странице читает текстовый файлик и его содержимое выводится на страницу с автообновлением. 
Тут же есть часть кода PHP, которая почему-то в части обращения по ssh , выполняет команду много раз (вот эта часть $ssh->exec...). Это я вижу по результату на сервере, результирующий файл постоянно создается по новой. Скорее всего она ($ssh->exec...) выполняется с интервалом, который стоит в setInterval(readTextFile, 1000) .

Но почему так происходит не понимаю.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
function date_range($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d' ) {

    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);

    while( $current <= $last ) {

        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }

    return $dates;
}
$ssh = new SSH2('10.00.00.00');
if (!$ssh->login('dff', '1234')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->exec('nohup bash -c \'i=(2018-12-02 2018-12-03 2018-12-04 2018-12-05 2018-12-06 2018-12-07 2018-12-08 2018-12-09 2018-12-10); for i in ${i[@]}; do zgrep \'20181202_01594110012_2225132\' /home/log.${i}.zip; done > /home/result.txt\' >/dev/null 2>&1 & exit');


?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Поиск</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    function readTextFile(file)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("autoScroll").checked; //if autoscrool is checked
    if(x==true){
     document.getElementById("textarea").scrollTop = document.getElementById("textarea").scrollHeight; //autoscroll
    }

    var filePath = "./tmp/Data.txt"

      $.ajax({
   dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
            $("#textarea").load(filePath);
            }
    });

}
setInterval(readTextFile, 1000);

</script>
<script>
function copy() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" , firstDay: 1 });
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" , firstDay: 1 });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<p><b>Дата от:</b> <input type="text" NAME="DATE1" id="datepicker"></p>
<p><b>Дата до:</b> <input type="text" NAME="DATE2" id="datepicker2"></p>
<input type="checkbox" name="OPTION2[]" value="POV">POV<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="OPTION2[]" value="SIB">SIB<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="OPTION2[]" value="SZ">SZ<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="OPTION2[]" value="UG">UG<br> 
<p><input type="submit" size="15" name="submit" Value="Искать"></p>
</form>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="15" cols="150" readonly autocomplete="off"></textarea>
<br>
<form>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="AutoScroll" id="autoScroll" label="Auto Scroll" checked>    Авто-прокрутка</label>
</form>
<button onclick="copy()">Копировать</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а зачем каждую секунду запускать AJAX запрос? и в паре с setInterval идет clearInterval(timerId), который возможно стоит повесить на success AJAX запроса?

Comment: А как это должно выглядеть? Ajax запускается чтобы выводить содержимое файла в онлайн.

Comment: >setInterval
для чего? обновлять "#textarea" каждую секунду?

Comment: Да. Возможно можно по другому сделать я не знаю.

Comment: ну собственно это и есть ответ на Ваш вопрос

Comment: Как сделать чтобы exec не выполнялся вместе с обновлением textarea?

Comment: Надо полностью изменять подход. При любом обращении к серверу (а выполнение одного ajax запроса - это новое обращение) php скрипт запускается заново. Как только он отдаст результат клиенту, соединение закрывается, а скрипт завершается (остаться работать он не может). Следовательно сам php скрипт должен уметь это корректно обрабатывать. Видимо при первом обращении он должен в фоне, отдельно от себя, запустить другой процесс, который запустит ssh и будет делать необходимые вещи. При повторных обращениях он должен забирать результат выполнения фонового скрипта и отдавать клиенту